# Writing functions in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I'm been ask to do a Jacobian in MatLab to solve the coordinates for the highest value for f(x) and also the max value for the same function.

The function I have to work with is : `f(x; y) = (x^3y + 5x^2y^2)/ e^(x^2+3y^4)`

so what I have accomplished so far:

```
function [j1,j2]=J(x)    
    [3*x(1)^2+20*x(1)*x(2)-36*x(1)^2*x(2)^4-120*x(1)*x(2)^5,10*x(1)^2-48*x(1)^3*x(2)^3-300*x(1)^2*x(2)^4;6*x(1)*x(2)+10*x(2)^2-8*x(1)^3*x(2)-30*x(1)^2*x(2)^2,3*x(1)^2+20*x(1)*x(2)-2*x(1)^4-20*x(1)^3*x(2)]     
end
```

I believe this is an matrix including all four derivatives of `f(x)`. Nut now I don't know how to solve my two questions.

Comment: i´ve tried to write max(J([x,y])) in command window, but got wrong kordinates....

Comment: and what an exact question would be?

Comment: How can I use my function to get the kordinates of the highest values of f(x,y) and how do i get the maxvalue of the given function?

Comment: Tanks for responding.

Comment: Anyone? please help, Im really stuck

Comment: no one who can answer how it works?  anything helps..

Comment: You should learn how to use the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html). The tutorials and examples there will be helpful for you.

Comment: if someone else having the same problem, i solved it like this;

Comment: &First i wrote the jocobian matris as ;  function A = J(x)
j11 = 6*x(1)*x(2)+10*x(2)^2-8*x(1)^3*x(2)-30*x(1)^2*x(2)^2;
j12 = 3*x(1)^2+20*x(1)*x(2)-2*x(1)^4-20*x(1)^3*x(2);
j21 = 3*x(1)^2+20*x(1)*x(2)-36*x(1)^2*x(2)^4-120*x(1)*x(2)^5;
j22 = 10*x(1)^2-48*x(1)^3*x(2)^3-300*x(1)^2*x(2)^4;
A = [j11, j12;j21, j22];
end

Comment: Then i used this function to estimate criticalpoints; function xnp1 = NewtonMultyVar(x0,N);
xn = x0;
for n = 1:N
xnp1 = xn - inv(J(xn))*z(xn);
xn = xnp1;
end
end  Where x0 is youre approximated point and N stands for number notations. hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was already given in the comments, to make sure the question will not remain unanswerd I will post it here:

First i wrote the jocobian matris as

```
function A = J(x) j11 = 6*x(1)*x(2)+10*x(2)^2-8*x(1)^3*x(2)-30*x(1)^2*x(2)^2; 
j12 = 3*x(1)^2+20*x(1)*x(2)-2*x(1)^4-20*x(1)^3*x(2); 
j21 = 3*x(1)^2+20*x(1)*x(2)-36*x(1)^2*x(2)^4-120*x(1)*x(2)^5; 
j22 = 10*x(1)^2-48*x(1)^3*x(2)^3-300*x(1)^2*x(2)^4; A = [j11, j12;j21, j22]; 
end
```

Then i used this function to estimate criticalpoints

```
function xnp1 = NewtonMultyVar(x0,N); 
xn = x0; 
  for n = 1:N 
    xnp1 = xn - inv(J(xn))*z(xn); 
    xn = xnp1; 
end 
end
```

Where `x0` is youre approximated point and `N` stands for number notations.